# Javascript - Show Asterisk or bullet dot in text fields and labels for which user dont have permission to view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement, wherein, I need to display asterisk or bullet dot for fields which user does not have view access. I do not want to hide the entire label or text but to show them as read only but with asterisk data.

Another thing that I want to ensure if, the asterisk or dot are just for viewing, but when I submit my form, I want the actual contents to be posted, instead of asterisk or dot.

I, had implemented it by using password type field for fields for which user does not have view access.
Is there any other better way or a Jquery plugin, that might be handy for this requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: THAT IS NOT SECURE! The clientside is the wrong place to be doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It defeats the purpose if you bring the read-only value to client side. No matter whether you show * in the field or not, user can read the value somehow because the value has been brought to client side. User can see the page source or page DOM using a debugger to see what data is on the page. User can also see the HTTP request/response to get the data. Therefore a pure client side solution will not work.

Your solution depends on how you render the page:

1. Server side rendering like JSP/PHP etc.: In this case you render the whole page contents from server. Therefore you can decide whether user has read permission on a field or not and render the field appropriately. Typically you would render the read only fields as a label with * so that (a) values never reach client - keeping it secure and, (b) field will not even be posted back to the server when the user posts the form to the server. On the server side you will handle the posted values as field level updates. That is necessary to avoid blanking out the read-only fields which are not even posted in the first place!
2. Client side rendering: In this case your client talks to the server using some kind of service. Recent trend is using a RESTful service responding with JSON content. In such a case  your JSON should indicate each field with its value and read-write permissions. Fields with read-only permissions should not have the value so that it is secure. Client side JS code should look at the read-only flag and render the data as a label with * in it. I am not aware of any ready-made JS component for doing this. You can implement a reusable component to go with the client side library you are using. For example - if you are using jQuery you can implement a jQuery plugin, if you are using angularJS you may implement a directive etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I am yet to implement the solution. I am aware, it wont be secure, so as an alternative, i thought of using a password field instead of regular text field. But as suggested by everyone, I guess, I should implement the behaviour at server side itself.

Comment: @AnoopGupta You should not send the fields without read permission to the client in any case. That means some server side code for sure. After that client side code is needed if your app is ajax driven (ma be jQuery or angular etc.) If you are rendering the whole page using a technology like JSP then you don't need any client side code. In any case remember to handle the post back carefully because it will have missing fields because read-only fields/or their data (depends on how you render read-only data) will not be posted to the server. You should carefully merge posted data.

Answer (score 1):

As saied by epascarello, this is not secure as even if you mask the content, user can easily modify the content by editing HTML and perform **HTML injections**.

If you want to do something like that, this should be done on Server Side (the service called)

Add more info on your architecture, what you have access to and what can not be modified and we may find a proper solution for that.